# Server set up using app.yaml, cron.yaml, etc. But directories aren't recognized

Tags: python, google-app-engine, wsgi, yaml

As the title says, the server has been configured to recognize sub directories but for whatever reason they are not being recognized when I load a web page. Is there any way to debug what is going on?

```
threadsafe: true
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /(.*\.html)
  static_files: html/\1
  upload: html/(.*\.html)

- url: /robots.txt
  static_files: html/robot.txt
  upload: html/robots.txt

- url: /pako
  static_dir: third_party/pako

- url: /images
  static_dir: images

- url: /js
  static_dir: js

- url: /css
  static_dir: css

- url: /compute/.*
  script: apprtc.app
  login: admin

- url: /probe.*
  script: probers.app
  secure: always

- url: /.*
  script: apprtc.app
  secure: always

libraries:
- name: jinja2
  version: latest
- name: ssl
  version: latest
- name: pycrypto
  version: latest

env_variables:
  BYPASS_JOIN_CONFIRMATION: false
  # Only change these while developing, do not commit to source!
  # Use appcfg.py --env_variable=ICE_SERVER_API_KEY:KEY \
  # in order to replace variables when deploying.
  ICE_SERVER_API_KEY: ""
  # Comma-separated list of ICE urls to return when no ice server
  # is specified.
  ICE_SERVER_URLS: ""
  # A message that is always displayed on the app page.
  # This is useful for cases like indicating to the user that this
  # is a demo deployment of the app.
  HEADER_MESSAGE: ""
```

Here is the response from the server

```
INFO     2021-08-12 05:20:35,496 admin_server.py:150] Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8000
INFO     2021-08-12 05:20:37,540 instance.py:294] Instance PID: 16382
INFO     2021-08-12 05:20:43,429 apprtc.py:95] Applying media constraints: {'video': {'optional': [{'minWidth': '1280'}, {'minHeight': '720'}], 'mandatory': {}}, 'audio': True}
WARNING  2021-08-12 05:20:43,436 apprtc.py:139] Invalid or no value returned from memcache, using fallback: null
INFO     2021-08-12 05:20:43,452 module.py:861] default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 8965
INFO     2021-08-12 05:20:43,520 module.py:861] default: "GET /css/main.css HTTP/1.1" 304 -
INFO     2021-08-12 05:20:43,575 module.py:861] default: "GET /js/util.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
INFO     2021-08-12 05:20:43,577 module.py:861] default: "GET /js/adapter.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
INFO     2021-08-12 05:20:43,629 module.py:861] default: "GET /js/constants.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
INFO     2021-08-12 05:20:43,631 module.py:861] default: "GET /js/infobox.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
INFO     2021-08-12 05:20:43,635 module.py:861] default: "GET /js/analytics.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
INFO     2021-08-12 05:20:43,639 module.py:861] default: "GET /js/sdputils.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
INFO     2021-08-12 05:20:43,643 module.py:861] default: "GET /js/call.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
INFO     2021-08-12 05:20:43,646 module.py:861] default: "GET /js/appcontroller.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
INFO     2021-08-12 05:20:43,698 module.py:861] default: "GET /css/main.css HTTP/1.1" 304 -
INFO     2021-08-12 05:20:43,709 module.py:861] default: "GET /js/peerconnectionclient.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
INFO     2021-08-12 05:20:43,699 module.py:861] default: "GET /js/adapter.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
INFO     2021-08-12 05:20:43,710 module.py:861] default: "GET /js/roomselection.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
INFO     2021-08-12 05:20:43,711 module.py:861] default: "GET /js/util.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
INFO     2021-08-12 05:20:43,712 module.py:861] default: "GET /js/signalingchannel.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
INFO     2021-08-12 05:20:43,751 module.py:861] default: "GET /js/stats.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
INFO     2021-08-12 05:20:43,764 module.py:861] default: "GET /js/storage.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
INFO     2021-08-12 05:20:43,768 module.py:861] default: "GET /js/sdputils.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
INFO     2021-08-12 05:20:43,773 module.py:861] default: "GET /js/constants.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
INFO     2021-08-12 05:20:43,776 module.py:861] default: "GET /js/infobox.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
INFO     2021-08-12 05:20:43,777 module.py:861] default: "GET /js/analytics.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
INFO     2021-08-12 05:20:43,806 module.py:861] default: "GET /js/appcontroller.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
INFO     2021-08-12 05:20:43,825 module.py:861] default: "GET /js/call.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
INFO     2021-08-12 05:20:43,836 module.py:861] default: "GET /js/peerconnectionclient.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
INFO     2021-08-12 05:20:43,840 module.py:861] default: "GET /js/roomselection.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
INFO     2021-08-12 05:20:43,841 module.py:861] default: "GET /js/stats.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
INFO     2021-08-12 05:20:43,842 module.py:861] default: "GET /js/signalingchannel.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
INFO     2021-08-12 05:20:43,858 module.py:861] default: "GET /js/storage.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
```

The server I'm configuring can be found [here](https://github.com/webrtc/apprtc). What I'm trying to do is create a server (that has already been written - just not configured) that takes video streams generated by my google glass and allows people to join a room where they can see my video stream. My google glass can then see their webcam feeds in my display. The platform I set the server up on is Debian 10. The tools are Google App Engine SDK for Python, Node.js, and Grunt. Part of the website is also written in Go.

The server is started by running

```
./collidermain -tls=true -port=8089 -room-server=http://example.com
```

And also running

```
python ../google-cloud-sdk/bin/dev_appserver.py --host example.com ./out/app_engine
```

The reason I'm asking for help is that the directories specified in the app.yaml file I show above are correctly placed relative to the index file that is used. So idk why it won't fetch them. The website is a replica of [this website](https://appr.tc/)

If you need me to elaborate further please let me know and I'll try!

So, it looks like that the webserver that this is designed to run on isn't meant to run on https. And the server itself won't function fully without an https connection.

Comment: Your question is lacking context. What are you trying to do? On what platform? With which tools? From what you are (not) saying, it could be anything (one may infer google-app-engine is involved, but that's it)

Comment: @AlienLifeForm  Hey I updated the post to hopefully provide more context and explain what the problem is. Let me know if you need additional information. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The software I set up is strictly for a dev environment meant to be run on localhost. In order to set up a production environment I have to use google web services. So that's why the website won't work.

For anyone who comes across this in the future:

1. You need ssl in order to be able to visit rooms in the software
2. ssl is not supported unless you use a google web service
3. you can configure the web service to use your domain so you have the option of setting up a sub domain or just out right use your main domain for the app.